# how to compare the order of growth between 2^((logn)^2) and n^3

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Is `2^((logn)^2)` having time complexity called quasi-polynomial time?
Also, how could I compare the time complexity between these two?

I couldn't think of a sufficient math proof that can convince myself.

Comment: You can certainly try integer values of `n` from 1 to 100, and see which function grows faster.

Comment: If you know the definition of quasi-polynomial time, then you will see that your expression follows it exactly. What confusion remains after that?

Comment: [Here's the definition.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Quasi-polynomial_time)

Comment: @user3386109 That would lead the OP astray; n^3 is eventually slower, but its growth is faster until somewhere between n=2^17 and n=2^18 (assuming log base 10). If the OP is using log base 2 then the switchover is much rapider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to go.

Say you take the log of both:

```
log(2^((log n)^2))
  = (log n)^2 * log 2

log(n^3)
  = 3 * log n
```

When *n* gets large enough, (log *n*)^2 will be much greater than log *n*. The constant factors `3` and `log 2` won't make a difference.

---

Another way to approach it is just to try a very large number. Suppose *n* = 10^100. Then log *n* = 100, and we have

```
2^((log n)^2)
  = 2^(100^2)
  = 2^10000
  = 19950631168807583848837421626835850838234968318861924548520089498529438830221946631919961684036194597899331129423209124271556491349413781117593785932096323957855730046793794526765246551266059895520550086918193311542508608460618104685509074866089624888090489894838009253941633257850621568309473902556912388065225096643874441046759871626985453222868538161694315775629640762836880760732228535091641476183956381458969463899410840960536267821064621427333394036525565649530603142680234969400335934316651459297773279665775606172582031407994198179607378245683762280037302885487251900834464581454650557929601414833921615734588139257095379769119277800826957735674444123062018757836325502728323789270710373802866393031428133241401624195671690574061419654342324638801248856147305207431992259611796250130992860241708340807605932320161268492288496255841312844061536738951487114256315111089745514203313820202931640957596464756010405845841566072044962867016515061920631004186422275908670900574606417856951911456055068251250406007519842261898059237118054444788072906395242548339221982707404473162376760846613033778706039803413197133493654622700563169937455508241780972810983291314403571877524768509857276937926433221599399876886660808368837838027643282775172273657572744784112294389733810861607423253291974813120197604178281965697475898164531258434135959862784130128185406283476649088690521047580882615823961985770122407044330583075869039319604603404973156583208672105913300903752823415539745394397715257455290510212310947321610753474825740775273986348298498340756937955646638621874569499279016572103701364433135817214311791398222983845847334440270964182851005072927748364550578634501100852987812389473928699540834346158807043959118985815145779177143619698728131459483783202081474982171858011389071228250905826817436220577475921417653715687725614904582904992461028630081535583308130101987675856234343538955409175623400844887526162643568648833519463720377293240094456246923254350400678027273837755376406726898636241037491410966718557050759098100246789880178271925953381282421954028302759408448955014676668389697996886241636313376393903373455801407636741877711055384225739499110186468219696581651485130494222369947714763069155468217682876200362777257723781365331611196811280792669481887201298643660768551639860534602297871557517947385246369446923087894265948217008051120322365496288169035739121368338393591756418733850510970271613915439590991598154654417336311656936031122249937969999226781732358023111862644575299135758175008199839236284615249881088960232244362173771618086357015468484058622329792853875623486556440536962622018963571028812361567512543338303270029097668650568557157505516727518899194129711337690149916181315171544007728650573189557450920330185304847113818315407324053319038462084036421763703911550639789000742853672196280903477974533320468368795868580237952218629120080742819551317948157624448298518461509704888027274721574688131594750409732115080498190455803416826949787141316063210686391511681774304792596709376

n^3
  = (10^100)^3
  = 10^300
  = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Of course, this is not a proof. There's no guarantee our *n* is large enough to get at the asymptotic behavior. But if your screen is wide enough, you can see that the first number is larger, and you can take that as a hint at least.

Comment: Thanks a lot with the clear explanation!